# Why doesn't the Ice King's crown affect Jake?

Tags: plot-explanation, adventure-time

In the season 3's "Thank You" Finn & Jake beat up the Ice King, and nearly at the end of the episode when the Ice King is restrained Jake takes his crown and wears it:

[image]

It's been said and shown in other episodes that the crown has certain "efects" on whoever wears it. That's what made the human Simon Petrikov into the Ice King after all, the same goes for Farmworld Finn.

How come that has no effect on Jake? Is he maybe immune to the crown's powers because he's a magic dog?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [*Adventure Time* Wikia](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Ice_King%27s_crown) says:

> Jake has been seen wearing the Ice King's crown in the episode "Thank You," though it had no effect. This is because Jake is already magic, according to Adam Muto.

and

> However, in the episode "Holly Jolly Secrets Part I," Gunter is seen wearing the crown and is also unaffected by its powers.

[Adam Muto](http://spring.me/MrMuto) does storyboards for *Adventure Time*.

Answer (score 2):

I have two theories on this:
The first is that the crown can only have one host at at time. So Jake can put on the crown and use its ice powers, but the crown is still connected to the Ice King and can't take over another mind at the same time. This would explain why it works on Finn in the episodes Finn the Human and Jake the Dog. Simon is dead, so the crown is able to take a new host.
My second theory is that the crown only has mind-altering effects on humans, which would still explain why it's only happened to Finn and Simon.
(I know this post is like 6 months old I'm sorry I just couldn't resist answering.)

Answer (score -1):

This could have been an oversight over the course of the shows production or: 
Potential spoilers ahead:

I noticed that it doesn't work on shape-shifters. 
When penguin Gunter wears it he doesn't change because he is actually Orgalorg. Jake is not only a magic shape-shifting dog, but it is later revealed that he is really the hybrid spawn of an interdimensional shape-shifting creature. Everyone else who has worn it, human or ortherwise, turned into a megalomaniacal ice wizard.